# error in spyder runfile('C:/Users/Archana/chatacter/WERE.py', wdir='C:/Users/Archana/chatacter')

Tags: python, image, ide, boolean, spyder

so I have just asked for a bool value while comparing two strings and it gives an error or whatever. i compiled on python shell AND it ran fine giving the desired output. can anyone tell me why spyder is behaving wired.. see image for more details.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oNbh.png

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing anything in your code, so that's why you are not getting anything in the console. If you change your code to `print("big" > "small")` you'll `False` printed in the console.